# dataTable editing for vertical table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm working on a dataTable editing plugin but it is not working for vertical orientation table. Attached is the table what I meant. Does any one know solutions?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There are no images or code attached.

Comment: Sorry, here is the screenshot: https://snag.gy/RrciAj.jpg Do you have any idea how to implement this with dataTable editing plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve vertical display with using [row details](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html).

Alternatively you can use Responsive extension and special classes for columns you want to see in row details, see [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/classes.html).

Comment: Ok, I figured it out with CSS. I have another query, I don't want to use the php library of editor plugin rather I'm using my own ajax script & output the data as json format. Is it possible to use this ajax script for inline editing and populate data accordingly?